# Cloudera quickstart docker: unable to run/start the container

Tags: docker, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am using windows 10 machine, with Docker on windows, and pulled cloudera-quickstart:latest image. while trying to run it, I am getting into below error.
can someone please suggest.

docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/bin/docker-quickstart\": stat /usr/bin/docker-quickstart: no such file or directory"

my run command:

> docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart

Comment: Have a look at: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Hadoop-101-Training-Quickstart/Docker-quickstart-images-issues-on-windows/td-p/35209

Comment: But my issue is different, docker deamon is not able to find /usr/bin/docker-quickstart script.

Answer (score 5):

The issue was that I have download docker separately and created the image with this command, which is not supported in cloudera 5.10 and above.

> tar xzf cloudera-quickstart-vm-*-docker.tar.gz
>
> docker import - cloudera/quickstart:latest < cloudera-quickstart-vm-*-docker/*.tar

so I finally removed the docker image and then pulled it properly

> docker pull cloudera/quickstart:latest

now docker is properly up and running.

Comment: I'm stuck on the same thing, Where did you find out that this is not supported in clouder 5.10 and above?

Comment: What is the problem with the import docker as I am unable to find anything like this at cloud-era/docker official document.

Answer (score 4):

If you had downloaded CDH v5.13 docker image, then the issue might be mostly due to the  structure of the image archive; in my case, I found it to be **clouder*.tar.gz > cloudera*.tar > cloudera*.tar** ! Seems the packaging was done by fault and the official [documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-13-x/topics/quickstart_docker_container.html#cloudera_docker_container) too doesn't capture this :( In which case, just perform one more level of extraction to get to the correct cloudera*.tar archieve. This [post](http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Hadoop-101-Training-Quickstart/is-CDH-513-docker-quick-start-really-working/td-p/78505) from the cloudera forum helped me.